# Associating String value with Integer value in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am working on a Spring-MVC project. I am using hibernate as the ORM mapping tool. This project lets 'user' perform CRUD operation on notes. The project window is called as a 'Canvas', and the user can have multiple canvases.
As a design perspective, it is always good to load the 'name' of canvas in frontend, and I can perform tasks using canvasid. I am just wondering how can I create and maintain a strict one-to-one association between the two. 
Please note, there are multiple users, so I have one-to-many relationship with person and notes, so some users will have same canvasid. I am posting the SQL code for 'Note' database below. Kindly have a look.

```
CREATE TABLE note
(
  noteid integer NOT NULL,
  sectionid integer,
  canvasid integer,
  text character varying,
  notecolor character varying,
  noteheadline character varying,
  id integer NOT NULL,
  noteorder integer,
  canvasname character varying,
  CONSTRAINT noteid PRIMARY KEY (noteid),
  CONSTRAINT user_note_fk FOREIGN KEY (id)
      REFERENCES person (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE note
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 0):

If Canvas is dynamic e.g. created by the user, you'll have to model it like an entity, holding the id and the name. This of course assumes a new table, and a foreign key constraint.

If Canvas is a concept that can be enumerated than you can use an enum in your code, and store an ordinal in your DB. No need for a new table or a canvasname column in this case

Comment: Thanks, Canvas is created by User, but I didn't wanted to make it more complex by creating an entity and maintaining the constraints. I thought there will be something like a Map in Java I can use.

Comment: If you wanted it persisted outside of memory, you'll have to create  an entity